# when I try to launch any driver the webpage is not getting loaded

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium2, firefoxdriver

> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect
>   to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
>   syncGUID":"{4ef3f74f-a8c6-4d0a-9f70-82419b95c42f}","version":"4.0.0","type":"extension","loader":null,"updateURL":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"optionsBrowserStyle":true,"aboutURL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Web
>   Compat","description":"Urgent post-release fixes for web
>   compatibility.","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"installDate":1560832941603,"updateDate":1560832941603,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"path":"C:\Program
>   Files\Mozilla
>   Firefox\browser\features\webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi","skinnable":false,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"toolkit@mozilla.org","minVersion":"59.0b5","maxVersion":null}],"targetPlatforms":[],"seen":true,"dependencies":[],"incognito":"spanning","userPermissions":{"permissions":["webRequest","webRequestBlocking"],"origins":[""]},"icons":{},"iconURL":null,"blocklistState":0,"blocklistURL":null,"startupData":null,"hidden":true,"installTelemetryInfo":null,"rootURI":"jar:file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mozilla%20Firefox/browser/features/webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi!/","location":"app-system-defaults"}
>   1562126737134 addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
>   1562126737134 addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Error: Synchronously loading the
>   add-ons
>   database(resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIDatabase.jsm:1310:15) JS
>   Stack trace: syncLoadDB@XPIDatabase.jsm:1310:15
>   startup@XPIProvider.jsm:2242:23 callProvider@AddonManager.jsm:204:31
>   _startProvider@AddonManager.jsm:655:5 startup@AddonManager.jsm:811:14 startup@AddonManager.jsm:2804:26 observe@addonManager.js:65:29
>   1562126737139 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on
>   formautofill@mozilla.org version 1.0
>   1562126737141 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on
>   fxmonitor@mozilla.org version 3.0
>   1562126737142 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on
>   screenshots@mozilla.org version 37.1.0
>   1562126737144 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on
>   webcompat@mozilla.org version 4.0.0
>   1562126737146 addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for
>   XPIProvider 1562126737147 addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished
>   startup: XPIProvider 1562126737147    addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting
>   provider: LightweightThemeManager
>   1562126737147 addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for
>   LightweightThemeManager 1562126737147 addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider
>   finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
>   1562126737148 addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
>   1562126737151 addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for
>   GMPProvider 1562126737151 addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished
>   startup: GMPProvider 1562126737151    addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting
>   provider: PluginProvider
>   1562126737151 addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for
>   PluginProvider 1562126737152  addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished
>   startup: PluginProvider 1562126737158 addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed
>   startup sequence 1562126739165    addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json
>   found. 1562126740368  addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering upgrade listener
>   for formautofill@mozilla.org 1562126740772    addons.xpi  DEBUG   Ignoring
>   file: name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\Users\HP
>   PC\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous2349729380597016166webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
>   1562126740773 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on
>   formautofill@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
>   1562126740773 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on fxmonitor@mozilla.org
>   in app-system-defaults 1562126740773  addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on
>   screenshots@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
>   1562126740774 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on
>   webcompat-reporter@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
>   1562126740774 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on webcompat@mozilla.org
>   in app-system-defaults 1562126740775  addons.xpi  DEBUG   scanForChanges
>   changed: false, state: {} JavaScript error:
>   resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm, line 2706: TypeError:
>   addon is null
>
> at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:112)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
>     at Test.FirstSeleniumTest.main(FirstSeleniumTest.java:9) Exception in
>   thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to
>   connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files\Mozilla
>   Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows: 
>   syncGUID":"{4ef3f74f-a8c6-4d0a-9f70-82419b95c42f}","version":"4.0.0","type":"extension","loader":null,"updateURL":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"optionsBrowserStyle":true,"aboutURL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Web
>   Compat","description":"Urgent post-release fixes for web
>   compatibility.","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"installDate":1560832941603,"updateDate":1560832941603,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"path":"C:\Program
>   Files\Mozilla
>   Firefox\browser\features\webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi","skinnable":false,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"toolkit@mozilla.org","minVersion":"59.0b5","maxVersion":null}],"targetPlatforms":[],"seen":true,"dependencies":[],"incognito":"spanning","userPermissions":{"permissions":["webRequest","webRequestBlocking"],"origins":[""]},"icons":{},"iconURL":null,"blocklistState":0,"blocklistURL":null,"startupData":null,"hidden":true,"installTelemetryInfo":null,"rootURI":"jar:file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mozilla%20Firefox/browser/features/webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi!/","location":"app-system-defaults"}
>   1562126737134 addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
>   1562126737134 addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Error: Synchronously loading the
>   add-ons
>   database(resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIDatabase.jsm:1310:15) JS
>   Stack trace: syncLoadDB@XPIDatabase.jsm:1310:15
>   startup@XPIProvider.jsm:2242:23 callProvider@AddonManager.jsm:204:31
>   _startProvider@AddonManager.jsm:655:5 startup@AddonManager.jsm:811:14 startup@AddonManager.jsm:2804:26 observe@addonManager.js:65:29
>   1562126737139 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on
>   formautofill@mozilla.org version 1.0
>   1562126737141 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on
>   fxmonitor@mozilla.org version 3.0
>   1562126737142 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on
>   screenshots@mozilla.org version 37.1.0
>   1562126737144 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on
>   webcompat@mozilla.org version 4.0.0
>   1562126737146 addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for
>   XPIProvider 1562126737147 addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished
>   startup: XPIProvider 1562126737147    addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting
>   provider: LightweightThemeManager
>   1562126737147 addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for
>   LightweightThemeManager 1562126737147 addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider
>   finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
>   1562126737148 addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
>   1562126737151 addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for
>   GMPProvider 1562126737151 addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished
>   startup: GMPProvider 1562126737151    addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting
>   provider: PluginProvider
>   1562126737151 addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for
>   PluginProvider 1562126737152  addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished
>   startup: PluginProvider 1562126737158 addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed
>   startup sequence 1562126739165    addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json
>   found. 1562126740368  addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering upgrade listener
>   for formautofill@mozilla.org 1562126740772    addons.xpi  DEBUG   Ignoring
>   file: name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\Users\HP
>   PC\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous2349729380597016166webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
>   1562126740773 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on
>   formautofill@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
>   1562126740773 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on fxmonitor@mozilla.org
>   in app-system-defaults 1562126740773  addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on
>   screenshots@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
>   1562126740774 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on
>   webcompat-reporter@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
>   1562126740774 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on webcompat@mozilla.org
>   in app-system-defaults 1562126740775  addons.xpi  DEBUG   scanForChanges
>   changed: false, state: {} JavaScript error:
>   resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm, line 2706: TypeError:
>   addon is null
>
> Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15
>   17:00:58' System info: host: 'LAPTOP-CEQKTEJ8', ip: '192.168.1.8',
>   os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_201' Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:124)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
>     at Test.FirstSeleniumTest.main(FirstSeleniumTest.java:9) Caused by:
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect
>   to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
>   syncGUID":"{4ef3f74f-a8c6-4d0a-9f70-82419b95c42f}","version":"4.0.0","type":"extension","loader":null,"updateURL":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"optionsBrowserStyle":true,"aboutURL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Web
>   Compat","description":"Urgent post-release fixes for web
>   compatibility.","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"installDate":1560832941603,"updateDate":1560832941603,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"path":"C:\Program
>   Files\Mozilla
>   Firefox\browser\features\webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi","skinnable":false,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"toolkit@mozilla.org","minVersion":"59.0b5","maxVersion":null}],"targetPlatforms":[],"seen":true,"dependencies":[],"incognito":"spanning","userPermissions":{"permissions":["webRequest","webRequestBlocking"],"origins":[""]},"icons":{},"iconURL":null,"blocklistState":0,"blocklistURL":null,"startupData":null,"hidden":true,"installTelemetryInfo":null,"rootURI":"jar:file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mozilla%20Firefox/browser/features/webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi!/","location":"app-system-defaults"}
>   1562126737134 addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
>   1562126737134 addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Error: Synchronously loading the
>   add-ons
>   database(resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIDatabase.jsm:1310:15) JS
>   Stack trace: syncLoadDB@XPIDatabase.jsm:1310:15
>   startup@XPIProvider.jsm:2242:23 callProvider@AddonManager.jsm:204:31
>   _startProvider@AddonManager.jsm:655:5 startup@AddonManager.jsm:811:14 startup@AddonManager.jsm:2804:26 observe@addonManager.js:65:29
>   1562126737139 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on
>   formautofill@mozilla.org version 1.0
>   1562126737141 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on
>   fxmonitor@mozilla.org version 3.0
>   1562126737142 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on
>   screenshots@mozilla.org version 37.1.0
>   1562126737144 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on
>   webcompat@mozilla.org version 4.0.0
>   1562126737146 addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for
>   XPIProvider 1562126737147 addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished
>   startup: XPIProvider 1562126737147    addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting
>   provider: LightweightThemeManager
>   1562126737147 addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for
>   LightweightThemeManager 1562126737147 addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider
>   finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
>   1562126737148 addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
>   1562126737151 addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for
>   GMPProvider 1562126737151 addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished
>   startup: GMPProvider 1562126737151    addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting
>   provider: PluginProvider
>   1562126737151 addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for
>   PluginProvider 1562126737152  addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished
>   startup: PluginProvider 1562126737158 addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed
>   startup sequence 1562126739165    addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json
>   found. 1562126740368  addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering upgrade listener
>   for formautofill@mozilla.org 1562126740772    addons.xpi  DEBUG   Ignoring
>   file: name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\Users\HP
>   PC\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous2349729380597016166webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
>   1562126740773 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on
>   formautofill@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
>   1562126740773 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on fxmonitor@mozilla.org
>   in app-system-defaults 1562126740773  addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on
>   screenshots@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
>   1562126740774 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on
>   webcompat-reporter@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
>   1562126740774 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on webcompat@mozilla.org
>   in app-system-defaults 1562126740775  addons.xpi  DEBUG   scanForChanges
>   changed: false, state: {} JavaScript error:
>   resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm, line 2706: TypeError:
>   addon is null
>
> at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:112)
>     ... 7 more

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have a version mismatch between Selenium and Firefox. As Firefox updates you also need to use the corresponding latest Selenium version.

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588082/webdriver-unable-to-connect-to-host-127-0-0-1-on-port-7055-after-45000-ms